# How to combine arrays with names to combine and output as an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

If I had 4 arrays of names (first, middle, last, and nickname) each with the same index number, how could I combine the arrays so the output would be one array with "first" ("nickname") "middle" "last"?

```
var arrayFirst = [John, Susan, Marise, George],
var arrayMiddle = [Ed, Margaret, Louise, Todd],
var arrayLast = [Smith, Johnston, Jones, Brown],
var arrayNickname = [Johnnie, Sue, Mary, Joe]
```

to output to:

```
var arrayFullName = [John Johnnie Smith, Susan Sue Margaret Johnston, and so on]?
```

Thank you!

Comment: please add your code. what does not work?

Answer (score 3):

You can iterate over any array using [`.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and use [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to populate the resultant array having names in desired format.

```js
const firstNames = ['John', 'Susan', 'Marise', 'George'];
const middleNames = ['Ed', 'Margaret', 'Louise', 'Todd'];
const lastNames = ['Smith', 'Johnston', 'Jones','Brown'];
const nickNames = ['Johnnie', 'Sue', 'Mary', 'Joe'];

const result = firstNames.map(
  (firstName, i) => `${firstName} (${nickNames[i]}) ${middleNames[i]} ${lastNames[i]}`
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope I've been helpful

```
const arrayFirst = ['John', 'Susan', 'Marise', 'George'];
const arrayMiddle = ['Ed', 'Margaret', 'Louise', 'Todd'];
const arrayLast = ['Smith', 'Johnston', 'Jones','Brown'];
const arrayNickname = ['Johnnie', 'Sue', 'Mary', 'Joe'];

var newArray = [];

for (let i = 0; i < arrayFirst.length; i++) {    
    newArray.push(arrayFirst[i] + " " + arrayNickname[i] + " " + arrayMiddle[i] + " " + arrayLast[i]);
}

console.log(newArray);
// [ 'John Johnnie Ed Smith', 'Susan Sue Margaret Johnston', 'Marise Mary Louise Jones', 'George Joe Todd Brown' ]
```

Comment: Yes, it is helpful. I need to run this through my process to see how it works. Thank you, again!

Comment: Thank you, for your help. I am going to have to table this for now. I got it to work as is, just didn't pursue the combining the arrays for names. Separate fields will work in my report for now. Or we can use Excel.

Comment: Thank you! I'm glad I was helpful!